# how to do padding a nested list

Tags: python, numpy

I have a nested list that contains 1002 time steps and in each time step, I have observation of 11 features. I have read docs related to padding but I really could not find out how to add zero elements at the end of each list. I found out the highest length of lists is for example the 24th item in my main list and now I want to pad all the rest elements based on this unless the 24th element that already in shape.As an example:

```
a = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,76,7],[2,2,3,4,2,5,5,5,,7,8,9,33,677,8,8,9,9],[2,3,46,7,8,9,],[3,3,3,5],[2,2],[1,1],[2,2]]

a[1] = padding(a[1],len(a[2]) with zeros at the end of the list)
```

I have done below:

```
import numpy as np
def pad_or_truncate(some_list, target_len):
    return some_list[:target_len] + [0]*(target_len - len(some_list))


for i in range(len(Length)):
    pad_or_truncate(Length[i],len(Length[24]))
    
    print(len(Length[i]))
```

or

```
for i in range(len(Length)):
   df_train_array = np.pad(Length[i],len(Length[24]),mode='constant')
```

and I got this error: `Unable to coerce to Series, length must be 11: given 375`

Comment: What should be the ideal output?

Comment: @SebastienD actually your solution was nice and useful, just I got this error `operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (788,11) (1163,) ` but I think I have to check something else

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use this simple line, which uses `np.pad`

```
list(map(lambda x: np.pad(x, (max(map(len, a)) - len(x), 0)).tolist(), a))
```

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 76, 7],
 [2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5, 5, 5, 7, 8, 9, 33, 677, 8, 8, 9, 9],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 46, 7, 8, 9],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 5],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2]]
```

Use this if you want to pad at the end instead:

```
list(map(lambda x: np.pad(x, (0, max(map(len, a)) - len(x))).tolist(), a))
```

Comment: I tried but again it gave me the same length for each list

Comment: I mean in the example above it works but I write it in my code to do nothing happens since my main list has 1002 time steps and in each time there is lots of observation.
But it was interesting that your solution is able to find the maximum length of the list.

Answer (score 3):

**Solution 1**

```
# set the max number of 0
max_len = max([len(x) for x in a])

# add zeros to the lists
temp = [x+ [0]*max_len for x in a]

#Limit the output to the wished length
[x[0:max_len] for x in temp]
```

**Solution 2** using `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df.fillna(0).astype(int).values.tolist()
```

**Output**

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 76, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5, 5, 5, 7, 8, 9, 33, 677, 8, 8, 9, 9],
 [2, 3, 46, 7, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [3, 3, 3, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
 ...]
```

Comment: the second solution did not work, the first one was able to determine the highest length of the list but again I could not increase the length by the max amount.

Comment: @john22 : would be happy to assist in case you have a further issue

Comment: @ Well, with using this line `MAX_LEN = np.expand_dims(max_len, axis=-1)` and replacing your effort with `temp = [x+ [0]*MAX_LEN for x in df_train_array]` the aforementioned issue became fixed. but now when I check the shape of temp or new list elements, these are the same with respect to before. I mean nothing happens after this. even, I stored the result in a new list but again nothing happened.

Answer (score 1):

The following code snippet should pad the individual lists with the appropriate number of 0s(driven by the size of the list with the maximum elements)

```
def main():
    data = [
        [1,2,3,4,5,6,76,7],
        [2,2,3,4,2,5,5,5,7,8,9,33,677,8,8,9,9],
        [2,3,46,7,8,9,],
        [3,3,3,5],
        [2,2],
        [1,1],
        [2,2]
    ]

    # find the list with the maximum elements
    max_length = max(map(len, data))

    for element in data:
        for _ in range(len(element), max_length):
            element.append(0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Your solution is also nice in the example but in real data, I got the error `'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'`. I tried to make my data a numpy array and I do not want to change it again